# Failed to convert value(s) to axis units: 'A'

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am tryng to plotting labelling data points in Seaborn Plots and I am facing a format problem.

Here is my code:

```py
# plot line graph
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(10,5)})
ax = sns.lineplot(x=bbCorpBRIT3['Quarter'], y=bbCorpBRIT3['Acessos'],data=bbCorpBRIT3,marker='*',color='#965786')
ax.set(title='Total Access')

# label points on the plot
for x, y in zip('Quarter','Acessos'):
     plt.text(x = x, # x-coordinate position of data label
              y = y, # y-coordinate position of data label, adjusted to be 150 below the data point
              s = '{}'.format(y), # data label, formatted to ignore decimals
              color = 'purple') # set colour of line
```

Here is the dataframe info:

```
# Column   Non-Null Count  Dtype
--------------------------------
0   Quarter  22 non-null     object
1   Acessos  22 non-null     int64
dtypes: int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 480.0+ bytes
```

Bellow a part of the Dataframe:

```
Quarter
2021Q1     645407
2021Q1     659598
2021Q1     674821
2021Q2     697064
2021Q2     718105
2021Q2     736580
2021Q3     754477
2021Q3     772991
2021Q3     790731
```

I am following the script of https://medium.com/swlh/quick-guide-to-labelling-data-for-common-seaborn-plots-736e10bf14a9 and would try to get the same results.

Comment: Maybe you could explain which line exactly gives the error? It also could help to [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74962547/edit) the full error trace to the post, as well as the exact version of matplotlib and seaborn you are using.

Comment: `for x, y in zip('Quarter','Acessos'):`  will let `x` iterate through the letters `Q,u,a,r,...` and `y`  through `A,c,e,s,...`.  You'll probably want to iterate through the values in the columns, so `for x, y in zip(bbCorpBRIT3['Quarter'], bbCorpBRIT3['Acessos']):`.  Note that as there are multiple rows with the same quarter, you'll be plotting 3 texts for each quarter.  Seaborn, on the contrary, averages out the positions for the line.